# Number parsing library

Tags: java, string, parsing, numbers

Where can I get a **smart** number parser, that can read a numeric String in, say...

- Integer form: -12345
- Decimal form: 123.45
- Exponential form: 15e-24
- Hexadecimal: #CAFEBABE
- Binary: b01100101

... and get me an **adequate** representation (from a `byte` if it fits, and up to a `GargantuanDouble` if it doesn't)?

I'm thinking in Java right now (Android), so if it's Java, all the better; but I'm willing to port a library small enough from another language.

Comment: Can I know why it was downvoted?

Comment: FWIW - regarding the adequate representation, with Java being statically typed and the Number interface being somewhat useless, you more or less have to know what you're parsing ahead of time size wise for small types.

Comment: We specifically discourage recommendation questions.  They are answered by links, which attract link rot and spam.  If you want to [edit] and change the question from "give me a library" to "how do I" please flag and ask for it to be reopened.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you can separate tokens, you can use [Integer.decode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29) for decoding the numbers.

> The sequence of characters following an (optional) negative sign
>   and/or radix specifier ("0x", "0X", "#", or leading zero) is parsed as
>   by the Integer.parseInt method with the indicated radix (10, 16, or
>   8). This sequence of characters must represent a positive value or a
>   NumberFormatException will be thrown. The result is negated if first
>   character of the specified String is the minus sign. No whitespace
>   characters are permitted in the String.

Eg.

```
Integer.decode("0xabcf123"); // hex
Integer.decode("07651");     // octal
Integer.decode("123459");    // decimal
```

Comment: Didn't know about that method! That covers most of the hassle, thanks

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn, It doesn't support binary, btw. You'll have to use `Integer.parseInt(value,radix)`

Answer (score 0):

Except the exponential form, you can handle each case and use Integer.parseInt(String a, int radix);